# Has somebody already used Meteor + mysql in a production environment?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor

I came across [mysql-live-select](https://github.com/numtel/mysql-live-select) wich seem to allow meteor to be used with a mysql database. Has somebody already used this package in a production environment ? Is there significant performance/reliability issues when using mysql as the database engine for meteor ?

Comment: Why would you want this? Just curious :-)

Comment: @KennethB I am developping a mobile application (using ionic) for an existing web application that uses a mysql database. The existing application is basically a social network so meteor reactive features are very appealing

Comment: Makes sense... Good luck... 

Comment: On this page http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-night-1.3-and-beyond you might find the second video, by Mike Seidle and Rick Wehrle from WorkHere, interesting. They affirm that if you treat mongo with Meteor as a form of cache you can use it with any kind of database. They also show a brief piece of code as to how they did it.

Comment: @mwarren That's a very interesting video, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that, but Meteor is based on NodeJS like Rails is to Ruby. You can use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) to create an endpoint to MySQL. The whole point of Meteor is to blur the distinction of Client-Server, you have to treat Sequelize like an AJAX endpoint or write a new library to use it from the client side.

Comment: mysql <-/-> Meteor; They don't go together. MongoDB or Redis or any other "modern" style db would be better. and the other dbs are way funner to code with

Comment: Haven't used it in prod..but played around..here's an interesting article that might help:https://projectricochet.com/blog/can-meteor-and-mysql-play-nicely-together#.Vt3w5_l97IU

Comment: Yes. I have used in production and it is working pretty good as there is official supported package https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql. But Some packages like Accounts is only works with mongo for authentication not other DB, So you to use customize authentication and authorization.